# Запрос с лимитом записей - ошибка: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, pagination

Уже как только не пробовал запросы с лимитом, но получаю ошибки:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE OFFSET 10 ROWS
```

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 933 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

БД: **Oracle 10g**

Ранее работал с версиями старше 10g, проблем вообще не было.

Comment: offset появился только в 12c1 на более ранних версиях надо использовать другие техники, например псевдоколонку rownum или row_number() (при доступности оконных функций)

Comment: _Ранее работал с версиями старше 10g, проблем вообще не было_, а с каким брендом СУБД вы работали?

Comment: @0xdb с 18c имел дело

Comment: Ааа, _с версиями старше 10g_, означает - 9i, 8i, итд. Вы наверное "моложе" имели ввиду, или другими словами - с более новыми.

Comment: Да все верно. С Ораклом работаю не часто, поэтому в оф документации ничего не нашел про лимитирование записией, думал что работает так же как и в более новых

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OFFSET`, а также `FETCH`, появились в 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.1) [см. row_limiting_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABHFGAA).

Попробуйте классический запрос для пагинации:

```
create table tab (id, memo) as 
    select level, 'memo '||level from dual connect by level<=100
/

select id, memo from (
    select q.*, rownum rn from (
        select * 
        from tab 
        order by id
    ) q where rownum <= 11
) where rn >= 9
/

        ID MEMO    
---------- --------
         9 memo 9  
        10 memo 10 
        11 memo 11
```

Или запрос покороче с аналитической функцией, он даст тот же результат:

```
select id, memo from (
    select tab.*, row_number() over (order by id) rn
    from tab)
where rn between 9 and 11
```

---

**Важно:** запрос в вопросе имеет ещё один недостаток, без `ORDER BY` его результат не детерминирован, то есть, сегодня он выведет: `1,2,3`, а завтра: `2,3,1`.